# Send Post Data from python to django

Tags: javascript, json, django, python-3.x, xmlhttprequest

i'm trying to transfer data from script in tempermonkey ( read userinput by form) to django.
Transfer works, but i can't use data in python (I think I'm doing something wrong in the format).

This is my script example in tempermonkey:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "www.example.com",
  data: datasend,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

datasend contain an array of objects like this:

```
 [{"name" : "Pippo" , "surname" : "Pluto" , "address" : "street xxx" , "number" : "1234"},{"name" : "aaa" , "surname" : "bbb" , "address" : "street xxx" , "number" : "4321"},{"name" : "y" , "surname" : "x" , "address" : "street xxx" , "number" : "333"}]
```

This is my view.py

```
def index(request):
    data=request.POST
    dataTransform=(json.loads(json.dumps(request.POST)))
    return HttpResponse(dataTransform)
```

The response is:

```
(u'[{"name" : "Pippo" , "surname" : "Pluto" , "address" : "street xxx" , "number" : "1234"},{"name" : "aaa" , "surname" : "bbb" , "address" : "street xxx" , "number" : "4321"},{"name" : "y" , "surname" : "x" , "address" : "street xxx" , "number" : "333"}]',u")
```

a dict with length=1. How can I access each element?
My goal is to save this information in Database.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Generally, you would use something like eval() for this, but you might want to look at this https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First send your data as JSON:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "www.example.com",
  data: JSON.stringify(datasend),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

and receive it properly:

```
def index(request):
    dataTransform=json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8")))
    for item in dataTransform:
        print(item["name"])
    return HttpResponse(dataTransform)
```

Comment: Thanks Matagus, 
I tried to transfer data with json header:
if receive it with only json.loads I get the following error: "TypeError: expected string or buffer" from django.

If I transfer data with json header and receive with json.dumps and then json.loads I get empy dict = {}

Comment: Now I've tried to implement your code but I get the following error:
"TypeError: expected string or buffer".
I don't understand.

Comment: You're running on python 3.x! I've updated my answer to decode the request body. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now works!!! I am a beginner and I was for hours on this problem. Thank thanks thanks
What is now the best  and right way to save information in Database?